# Getting a responsive bootstrap form inside a dhtmlx modal window

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dhtmlx

A software I am working on have a dhtmlx modal window with multiple tabs in it. In each of those tab, a generated form is shown (based on data). The forms are made of JavaScript, JQuery and some dhtmlx controls.

I am currently trying to get responsive forms using bootstrap (as dhtmlx is not responsive).

I have two problems:

1. The dhtmlx modal window does not refresh the content dynamically, it waits until the resize is done to refresh the content. I need the content to be dynamically reorganized by bootstrap while I resize the modal window.
2. Bootstrap `col-*-*` grid system react to the screen size, not the modal window size. I need my form to react to the modal window size. As an example, if my modal window is large, I need multiple columns in my form, but if it is small, I need only one column. In [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davidgourde/epka5god/), the inside of the dhtmlx window is not responsive with bootstrap.

If that is not possible or not a good idea to keep the dhtmlx modal window (will it break the responsive design I need?), is it possible to replace a dhtmlx window with a bootstrap modal without starting from scratch again?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to do this in an elegant way, so I did it the hard way. This is the solution I will use (and that works).

I wrote an example were I change the classes as I need for how I use bootstrap in my form, but you can easily adapt this to your own needs.

```
window.attachEvent("onResizeFinish", function(obj){
    deleteClassCol();
    if (obj.getDimension()[0] < 768)
    {
      $('.form-group').addClass('col-xs-12');
      $('.label-control').addClass('col-xs-12');
      $('.theInput').addClass('col-xs-12');
    }
    else if (obj.getDimension()[0] < 992)
    {
      $('.form-group').addClass('col-xs-6');
      $('.label-control').addClass('col-xs-2');
      $('.theInput').addClass('col-xs-10');
    }
    else if (obj.getDimension()[0] < 1200)
    {
      $('.form-group').addClass('col-xs-4');
      $('.label-control').addClass('col-xs-2');
      $('.theInput').addClass('col-xs-10');
    }
    else
    {
      $('.form-group').addClass('col-xs-3');
      $('.label-control').addClass('col-xs-2');
      $('.theInput').addClass('col-xs-10');
    }
});

function deleteClassCol(){
    [".form-group", ".label-control", ".theInput"].forEach(function(theClass) {
    $(theClass).removeClass (function (index, css) {
        return (css.match (/(^|\s)col-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
        });
    });
}
```